# Получить значения из файла json

Tags: javascript, json

Прошу помочь разобраться с Json.
Есть файл с таким содержанием

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 124,
  "created": "2015-08-26T16:32:26Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "quote": [
    {
     "Symbol": "YHOO",
     "Date": "2010-03-10",
     "Open": "16.51",
     "High": "16.940001",
     "Low": "16.51",
     "Close": "16.790001",
     "Volume": "33088600",
     "Adj_Close": "16.790001"
    },
    {
     "Symbol": "YHOO",
     "Date": "2010-03-09",
     "Open": "16.41",
     "High": "16.719999",
     "Low": "16.40",
     "Close": "16.530001",
     "Volume": "20755200",
     "Adj_Close": "16.530001"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Как из файла в js получить значения массива, например "Close"? Не получается именно из подключенного файла json получить данные.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример кода ниже выводит все значения `Close` в консоль:

```
var obj = {
 "query": {
  "count": 124,
  "created": "2015-08-26T16:32:26Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "quote": [
    {
     "Symbol": "YHOO",
     "Date": "2010-03-10",
     "Open": "16.51",
     "High": "16.940001",
     "Low": "16.51",
     "Close": "16.790001",
     "Volume": "33088600",
     "Adj_Close": "16.790001"
    },
    {
     "Symbol": "YHOO",
     "Date": "2010-03-09",
     "Open": "16.41",
     "High": "16.719999",
     "Low": "16.40",
     "Close": "16.530001",
     "Volume": "20755200",
     "Adj_Close": "16.530001"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
};
for(i = 0; i < obj.query.results.quote.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj.query.results.quote[i].Close);
}
```

Единственный открытый вопрос - в каком виде Вы получаете JSON. Если в виде строки, то его предварительно необходимо преобразовать в объект: `var obj = JSON.parse("{ ... }");`